# Can't connect to Postgresql with PHP

Tags: php, apache, postgresql

I have Apache 2.4, Postgresql 9.3 and PHP 5.5 on Windows Server 2007. I am getting the following error when I try to connect to Postgresql from PHP:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function pg_connect()
```

So far I have done the following: 
Added C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin to my environment variables 
modified php.ini - I uncommented the folling lines:

```
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

I tried adding this line to my httpd.conf file:

```
LoadFile "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin/libpq.dll"
```

But when I do that I get the following error when I try to restart the server:

```
Syntax error on line 177 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf:
Cannot load C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/libpq.dll into server: 
%1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Comment: Have you restarted apache after you edited your `php.ini` file? Also, make sure so that you edit the correct php.ini file, you can check what ini file is loaded using `phpInfo()`. You should also check so `php_pgsql.dll` is located in your extension folder.

Comment: I have restarted after editing php.ini without the "LoadFile" edit to httpd.conf.

Comment: From phpInfo(): Loaded configuration file: C:\php\php.ini.

Comment: Hopefully this will be one of many experiences that brings you to realize that Windows is a waste of time for trying to serve/develop anything, and leads you to linux (or OSX).

Comment: Looks like whatever PHP flavour you installed wasn't compiled with PostgreSQL support - or at least not the legacy PostgreSQL interface, it might still have PDO for PostgreSQL (which is what you should be using anyway). Where did you get this PHP install from?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of "%1 is not a valid win32 application".
My problem was because I had installed 64-bit postgres but my apache and php were 32-bit. once i changed postgres to the 32-bit version, the problem went away.

Comment: Well, postgreSQL doesn't exist for Win32 in newer versions.